How can I find the total number of US visas granted to Pakistanis from Pakistan and Indians from India in 2023?
How can I find the

total number of US visas granted to Pakistanis from Pakistan and Indians from India in 2023?
How many applied and how many were rejected?

Which website of the US state department shows this?

The US Department of State publishes visa statistics on its website.  These are broken down by issuing post or by nationality, but not by both simultaneously, nor by place of residence.  I'm not aware of a source that would allow you to calculate the numbers you seek.
